# how can find this inequality max

Tags: inequality

give  $n,k\ge 1$,and $n,k\in N,a_{i},c_{i}\ge0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$,such at

(1):$a_{1}\ge a_{2}\ge\cdots a_{n}$,and $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=1$

(2)when $m=1,2,\cdots,n$ have $c_{1}+c_{2}+\cdots+c_{m}\le m^k$

find this $\max{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}a^k_{i}}$

Comment: $m=1,2,3,4,\cdots,n$

Comment: oh sorry, is $c_{1}+c_{2}+\cdots+c_{m}$

Comment: I think this reslut is $1$.

Comment: If I understand the question right, a maximum of $n^{k-1}$ should be possible.

Assuming given $1 \le n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have free choice of $a_i, c_i \ge 0$ such that the conditions are met,  

choose $a_i = \dfrac{1}{n}$ and $c_i = i^k - (i-1)^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We argue this way to prove $n^{k-1}$ is the maximum.  First we choose the $c_i$.

$c_1$ must be $1$, as in the final weighted sum all terms are positive, and the only reason to reduce $c_1$ would be to shift its weight to some other $c_j$.  However the corresponding multiplier $a_j \le a_1$, so this process cannot increase the maximum.  By similar reasoning, each $c_i = i^k - (i-1)^k$, the maximum possible given choices for preceding $c_i$.

Now, we have $c_i > c_j$ for $i > j$.  So we would like to choose the highest possible weight for $a_n$.  However as $a_n \le a_i$ for all $i$, the best we can do here is choosing $a_i = \dfrac{1}{n}$ for all $i$.

This leads to a maximum of $n^{k-1}.$

Comment: Why $c_1$ must be $1$? I don't even understand this...

Comment: @julien: The inequality constraint (2) for $m=1$ restricts $c_1 \le 1$.  So we can choose any number for $c_1 \in [0, 1]$.  As the function we are trying to maximise has positive coefficient for $c_1$, we should try finding the largest permissible value for $c_1$. If we decide on a value $c \lt 1$, the only potential benefit is that we can distribute $1-c$ among other $c_i$ to increase them. But this is not beneficial, as the coefficients of all other $c_i$ are not larger than the coefficient of $c_1$, because $a_1 \ge a_i$.  Hence $c_1 = 1$ is the best choice.  Hope that's clearer.

Comment: You could show all this using calculus and Lagrange multipliers if you wish, though that's messy given the number of constraints.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced, thanks a lot. I feel more comfortable with the messy calculus proof though. For a while, I though we could do this with Abel summation, but it did not lead me anywhere.